# vb6 looping through an array

Tags: arrays, loops, vb6

I have a simple loop where I go through a bunch of items, and if there are corresponding values (subitems), then mark them completed.

```
For x = 0 To UBound(strArray)
    For Each itmx In lvwThings.ListItems
        If strArray(x) = itmx.SubItems(1) Then
            itmx.Selected = True
        End If
    Next itmx
Next x
```

My problem is, if I have 3 values, say 1,2,3 only the third one will get selected. How do I change it so that all values get selected?

Comment: Do you have the listview `MultiSelect` property set to True?

Comment: WOW. thanks, I guess problem solved!